# Easyocr is running fine in the python code, but throwing error when converted into an exe file

Tags: python, opencv, executable, auto-py-to-exe, easyocr

This is my python code:

```
import easyocr
cropped_image_path = 'D:\\Desktop\\screens\\screens\\1.png'
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
easy_results = reader.readtext(cropped_image_path)
print(easy_results)
print("Extracted text is: ", easy_results[0][1])
```

Following is the error that I got after converting it to exe using auto-py-to-exe library:

Neither CUDA nor MPS are available - defaulting to CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "easyocr_check.py", line 11, in \<module\>
File "easyocr\\easyocr.py", line 452, in readtext
File "easyocr\\easyocr.py", line 321, in detect
File "easyocr\\detection.py", line 95, in get_textbox
File "easyocr\\detection.py", line 55, in test_net
File "easyocr\\craft_utils.py", line 236, in getDetBoxes
File "easyocr\\craft_utils.py", line 31, in getDetBoxes_core
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
\[8260\] Failed to execute script 'easyocr_check' due to unhandled exception!
```

Version of python and libraries that I am using:
Python v3.9
easyocr v1.7.0
opencv-python v4.7.0.72
auto-py-to-exe v2.36.0

I am expecting the following output which I am getting from the python code, but not from the exe.:

[([[23, 5], [59, 5], [59, 19], [23, 19]], '21.23', 0.9985201957308608)]
Extracted text is:  21.23

Comment: why are there all those backslashes in your question? they destroy the formatting. undo those.

Comment: Why would you create this trouble for yourself? The easiest solution to problems with py2exe, pyinstaller, autopytoexe, etc etc etc is _just to not use them_. They make your software slower to run, larger/harder to distribute, more amenable to legal problems (since you're redistributing dependencies yourself as opposed to providing code to your clients that _they_ can use to install those dependencies), more fragile in the face of differences between build and deployment environments, etc etc.

Comment: Granted, I come from the UNIX world where tools to let a user install your program and all its dependencies _as separate packages_ by running a single command are well-established and robust, so there's a certain level of privilege there.